# Finding all subsets of an array and sum of the individual subsets to an different array in c language

Tags: c, arrays, subset-sum

Please specify complete program...

for example,

```
a[2] = {3,1};
```

subsets will be

```
{}
{3}
{1}
{3,1}
```

sum of the individual subsets will be

```
{}    -> 0
{3}   -> 3
{1}   -> 1
{3,1} -> 4
```

this sum of the individual subsets in an array like

```
aa[] = {0,3,1,4};
```

**EDIT**: I have tried this:

- `n` is the size of array
- `a` is the input array
- `aa` is the output array contains sum of individual subsets.

Here is the code:

```
aa[0] = 0;
z = 1;
for (c = 1; c <= n; c++) {
    for (d = 0; d <= n - c; d++) {
        if (c == 1) {
            sum1 += a[d];
        } else {
            k = d + c - 1;
            for (j = k; j < n; j++) {
                 for (i = d; i < k; i++)
                     sum1 += a[i];
                 sum1 += a[j];
            }
        }
        aa[z] = sum1;
        z++;
        sum1 = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: hint: there are `2**n` different subsets in an array of `n` elements, a simple solution for sets upto 30 elements will suffice.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your solution does not work: you are only summing contiguous subsets.  The assignment tells you to find **all** subsets.

A simple way to enumerate all subsets is to iterate with a loop index from `0` to `2**n - 1` and to consider each of the low order n bits in the index to be an indicator of inclusion in the current subset.  With 32 bit ints, you can use a `unsigned int` as an index for sets of up to 30 elements if you can allocate the output array (4GB).  Larger sets would require a 64 bit index and generate a truly huge output array.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *compute_subset_sums(int *a, int n) {
    int *aa = calloc(1ULL << n, sizeof(int));
    if (aa != NULL) {
        /*---------------------cut here--------------------*/
        for (size_t i = 0; (i >> n) == 0; i++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if ((i >> j) & 1)
                    sum += a[j];
            }
            aa[i] = sum;
        }
        /*---------------------cut here--------------------*/
    }
    return aa;
}
```

Comment: I want to find all subsets of an array and the subset sums in an array named 'aa' as i tried in my example....

Comment: The code above does just that! Remove the function definition and the array allocation if `aa` is already an array of the appropriate size.  Cut along the dotted lines.